# Jenkins pipeline: update image before docker.image().inside()

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline described in a Jenkinsfile.

During the build step I start a docker container in which all build steps are executed. Something like this:

```
docker.image('node:8').inside() { }
```

I notice that this does not fetch the latest docker image but always uses the image that was originally pulled from the docker hub. I was expecting that this would check with the docker hub if the `node:8` image is still up-to-date and fetch a new image if not. How can I trigger a new image download if my local registry does not have the latest image cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pull the image, this will only download image layers that have changed:

```
sh 'docker pull node:8'
```

Comment: I am basically doing that now, but through the pipeline api, something like this `docker.image('node:8').pull()`.

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that the docker variable reference of Jenkins mentions, that for the `inside` function no pull is necessary, which led me to assume that it will also pull on repeated invocations, but it seems that the image is only pulled if its not yet present on the system.

Answer (score 2):

To update the image without falling back to the shell you can add `docker.image("node:8").pull()`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can do is to remove the local image before building .

```
docker rmi image_name
```

in bash shell prompt in jenkins

Comment: I don't want to do that, because that invalidates the whole idea of caching. The image that I use might only be updated every few month or so, but I usually build my project multiple times a day and I do not want to download a new image during each build. I need a solution which only downloads a new image if a new upstream version is available.